# sendmail + SASL2 Auth Error

Tags: sendmail

My sendmail config is like so:

`/usr/lib/sasl2/Sendmail.conf`
`pwcheck_method:saslauthd`

We are running "saslauthd"

`root     32102     1  0  81   0 -  1128 fcntl_ 11:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam`

When I saslauth with account name "cccc" everything works OK. But when I saslauth with account name "cccc@domain.com" it fails.

`/var/log/messages`
`saslauthd[32103]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=cccc] [service=smtp] [realm=domain.com] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]`

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your saslauthd is using pam as the backend for authentication.

Mostly on a system the smtp/imap check is just a lookup of you system account.

And there are no system accounts like whatever@domain.com. So pam cannot find such a user and so rejecting authentication.

Take a look in /etc/pam.d/smtp

If you really want using pam, which I would suggest you, you can use a mysql table for your authentication or other fancy things. Take a look at pam-mysql e.g.

Either use a apropriate setup for you pam or use sasldb as a backend for sasalauthd

saslauthd -a sasldb

Then you can use the userland tool saslpasswd2 for setting up your accounts.